# How to apply a Hapi.js plugin to specific routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a server I built with Hapi.js. I created a plugin to restrict access to some local network IP addresses, like this:

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
    server.ext({
        type: 'onRequest',
        method: function (request, reply) {
            console.log(request);
            if (
                request.info.remoteAddress.indexOf("192.") !== 0 &&
                request.info.remoteAddress.indexOf("127.") !== 0
            ) {
                return reply.view('error', {
                    error: "I DON'T LIKE YOU"
                });
            }
            return reply.continue();
        }
    });
    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    pkg: { "name": "localOnly" }
};
```

I want to apply this plugin to only "/pathA", while keeping "/pathB" and "/pathC" accessible to all users. Therefore I tried doing this:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8000 });
server.register(require('vision'), err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    server.views(/* removed for brevity */);
    server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/pathB', handler: handlerB });
    server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/pathC', handler: handlerC });
    server.register(require('./plugins/localOnly.js'), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/pathA', handler: handlerA });
        server.start(/* removed for brevity */);
    });
});
```

However, it seems that my plugin intercepts all connections. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? It's OK if you suggest me to make a complete refactor. I'm just planning the app at this stage and wanted to give Hapi.js a shot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does it need to be in a plugin? If not, you could use a route level extension point. For example:

### Route-level extension

```
const restrict = function (request, reply) {

    if (/^(192|127)/.test(request.info.remoteAddress)) {
        return reply('Blocked');
    }

    return reply.continue();
};

server.route({
    config: {
        ext: {
            onPreAuth: { method: restrict }
        }
    },
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/pathA',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('Hello!');
    }
});
```

Another approach using a plugin:

### Add route inside plugin using `sandbox: plugin`

```
const plugin = function (server, options, next) {

    const restrict = function (request, reply) {

        if (/^(192|127)/.test(request.info.remoteAddress)) {
            return reply('Blocked');
        }

        return reply.continue();
    };

    // only applies to route in this plugin

    server.ext('onPreAuth', restrict, { sandbox: 'plugin' }); 

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/pathA',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Hello!');
        }
    });

    return next();
};
```

Comment: Having it as a "Route-level extension" suits me perfectly! Thank you for your help and time! I wish I could up-vote you too but not allowed to do that yet, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions of Hapi (currently v17) then you will need to pass route options as `route.options.plugins['myPluginName']` e.g.

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/home',
  options: {
    plugins: {
       myPluginName: true
    }
  }
}
```

This can be picked up in the plugin under `ext` hooked into `onPreAuth` or later. e.g.

```
register: async (server, options) => {
  server.ext({
    type: 'onPreAuth',
    method: async (request, h) => {
      // Exit early if the route is not configured for this route
      if (!request.route.settings.plugins.myPluginName) { return h.continue }
      // ... runs before the route handler ...
    }
  })
}
```

Note that the hook must be later than `onRequest` in the [Hapi lifecycle](https://futurestud.io/files/hapi/hapi-request-lifecycle.pdf) since the route has not been loaded at that point. If you want to access authentication stuff then you will have to use `onPostAuth`.

This approach has the benefit of being loosely coupled between routes and plugin.